# PERFORMANCE: Symfony Cache in RAM disk a good idea?

Tags: performance, symfony

I'm running a Symfony 3 APP, on Apache 2.4 with PHP 7.3.
**Memcached, opcache and apcu are enabled** and configured as per the performance guide of the Symfony documentation. So I thought I was all set up...

But then I found this text:
Symfony makes heavy use of a filesystem cache. By default, the cache is located in app/cache/ENV where ENV is the environment currently accessed.

Which I interpret as the cache being stored in a directory on the FS (which is usually a hard drive), hence here's my question:

**Would it be of any help to the Symfony application's performance if I was to run the cache directory in a RAM disk?**

Thank you!

PD: If you know of any good guide on how to improve Symfony's performance in relationship with the database from a SysAdmin/DevOps perspective, I would be very grateful if you could share a link with me.

Comment: you don't need to use filesystem for Symfony's framework caching, see [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/cache.html#configuring-cache-with-frameworkbundle), for Symfony 3.4 see [here](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/cache.html#configuring-cache-with-frameworkbundle)

Answer (score 0):

> Would it be of a​n​y help to the Symfony application's performance if I was to run the cache directory in a RAM disk?

I don't think so. The cache files contain compiled files, like classes and templates. These files are then cached by OPcache in memory.

The Performance section of the documentation covers most things:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/performance.html#performance-checklists